# The matrix A in the system of Euler Equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am running a simulation on a 1D Euler equations:

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial (\rho u)}{\partial x}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial (\rho u)}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial (\rho u^2+\rho)}{\partial x}=0$$$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial ((E+P)u)}{\partial x}=0$$

The above system can be written into a vector equation:

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial (F(U))}{\partial x}=0$$, where $U=(\rho,\rho u, E)^T$, $F(U)=(\rho u, \rho u^2, (E+P)u)^T$. In addition, to make the system closed, the following relations are imposed:

$$E=\frac{1}{2}\rho u^2+\rho e, \ e=\frac{P}{(\gamma-1)\rho}$$

I am using Godunov's 2nd order method. Owing to the complexity of dealing with a nonlinear system, I have to convert the vector equations into something like this:
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+ A\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=0$$, where $A$ is a matrix. $A$ is not necessarily a constant matrix in general setting, but locally it is. Can someone help me in determining what $A$ is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**A** is the Jacobian matrix which can be written in terms of both primitive and conservative variables. You already defined the conservative variables (**U**). To distinguish conservative variables (**U**) from the speed *u*, the conservative variables are shown with *q* such as:

$$
\mathbf{Q}
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
q_1 \\
q_2 \\
q_3
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\rho \\
\rho u \\
E
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Whereas the primitive variables are:

$$
\mathbf{P}
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\rho \\
u \\
E
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

You have given fluxes (**F**) in terms of primitive variables. **F** can also be written in terms of conservative variables such as:

$$
\mathbf{F}
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
f_1 \\
f_2 \\
f_3
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
q_2 \\
\frac{q_2^2}{q_1} \left( 1-0.5\hat{\gamma} \right) + \hat{\gamma}q_3 \\
\frac{q_2}{q_1} \left( q_3\gamma - \frac{\hat{\gamma}q_2^2}{2q_1} \right)
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

where, $\gamma$ is the ratio of specific heats and $\hat{\gamma} = \gamma - 1$.

**A** is defined as:

$$
\mathbf{A}
=
\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{Q}}
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial q_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial q_2} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial q_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial q_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial q_3} &
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial q_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial q_1} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial q_2} &
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial q_3}
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

It is left to take derivatives one by one. As a result, **A** is (I worked out the derivatives myself so it may contain mistakes):

$$
\mathbf{A}
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\frac{q_2^2}{q_1^2} \left( 1-0.5\hat{\gamma} \right) & 2\frac{q_2}{q_1} \left( 1-0.5\hat{\gamma} \right) & \hat{\gamma} \\
-\frac{\gamma q_2 q_3}{q_1^2} + \frac{\hat{\gamma}q_2^3}{q_1^3} & \frac{\gamma q_3}{q_1} - 3\frac{\hat{\gamma}q_2^2}{2q_1^2} & \frac{q_2\gamma}{q_1}
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

**A** can also be written in terms of **primitive** variables such as (taken from reference 1 (see below)):

$$
\mathbf{A}
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\hat{\gamma}H - u^2 - a^2 & (3-\gamma)u & \hat{\gamma} \\
\frac{1}{2}\left[(\gamma - 3)H-a^2\right] & H-\hat{\gamma}u^2 & \gamma u
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

where, *H* and *a* are the total enthalpy and the speed of sound, respectively:

$$H = \frac{E+p}{\rho}$$

$$a = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma p}{\rho}}$$

**Reference 1**: Riemann Solvers and Numerical Methods for Fluid Dynamic, F. Toro

Comment: mistake: for the first $\mathbf{A}$, the third row first column should be $-\gamma q_2 q_3 / q_1^2 + \hat{\gamma} q_2^3 / q_1^3$. so the error is for the 1/2 factor.

Comment: @ArtificiallyIntelligence Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

A is the jacobian matrix of the system.
basically it is partial derivative of variable with respect to independent variables.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

It is used to decouple the coupled equations,so that solving can be easily done.
Im too working on euler equations but no luck still.Im coding in modelica.